# Best time expansion for a voice - ADR Editing

Tags: editing, voice

I just recorded a bit of ADR and I need to expand the person's syllable about 6 frames longer (he didn't emphasize a word properly - unfortunately it was his first time doing ADR and he didn't have a firm grasp of timing and tempo and I've got to help him out a bit)

What is the best plug-in or method to expand it keeping the pitch the way it is and not adding in many artifacts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Utopia, "6 frames longer" than how many? What kind of percentage are you talking about here? I won't be able to help, although I believe my comment is relevant to the question. You have tried editing several takes together? I know it's not easy on vowels although I sometimes find it just works.

Comment: @Justin Sorry - one syllable, "Thou" in "Thousand" needs to be emphasized and he didn't do that, he said it straight, so I need to make that syllable which is 5 frames long 6 frames longer, which is a little more than double the length. Can't really use other takes because the good takes where he said it correctly have a huge Harley motorcycle ripping through his voice. lol

Answer (score 2):

Since Pitch n Time was mentioned, I'll only add that the "v" setting (meaning " for voice") would be the best algorithm for your intended use. Although I will also say that I usually end up having to live with more digital artifacts than i would like when using this tool.

My advice would be to try Elasic Time, which comes with the latest versions of PT. Very easy to use, non-destructive, and pretty forgiving when it coes to long stretches.

Answer (score 1):

Serato Pitch 'n Time Pro is a great tool for ADR syncing, especially when using the voice time expansion algorithm and the waveform comparison panel.

Comment: Thank you. Trying this out. I have Pitch n' Time but never really got it to work well on voice, just music. But, trying it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the preferences for TCE to "male voice" in one of the preferences windows, you can make the stock protools time expansion work better with the material when you are using it as a tool. If it sounds too bad, you can perhaps just stretch it only 4 frames and make the pause between "thou" and "sand" a little longer. You can also cheat a bit by starting the syllable "thou" a frame later, if you can't get rid of the artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I agree. Try to use elastic audio and warp markers.  You can cheat it by using a separate track and copy and paste the second part of that syllable to the 2nd track for emphasis

Answer (score 0):

What sample rate did you record at? That will have a huge bearing on how well you can achieve this..... 96k or higher is always advisable

Comment: I recorded at 96K. The tools I have are Time Shift, stock Pro Tools and Serato Pitch n' Time and I have access to anything made by Waves.